# Displaying an integer with canvas.drawText

Tags: java, android, canvas

Currently I have an integer that is incremented every time a sprite is touched, what I want to do is then display this on the canvas. Currently I have it like this:

```
public void doDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBackgroundImage, 0, 0, null);
    sprite.draw(canvas); 
    //Draw all the objects on the canvas
    canvas.drawText("Number of hits: ",  5,25, paint);
    canvas.drawText(displayTime,  5,250, paint);
}
```

What I want to do is after it says number of hits it will display the number of times the sprite has been touched with the integer that is named hitCount

Comment: `String.valueOf(myinteger)` is that what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
canvas.drawText("Number of hits: " + String.valueOf(hitCount),  5,25, paint);
```